# how to connect cystal reports to oracle databse server

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports, oracle11g

Hi am Using Crystal Reports 8.5  and oracle 11g when I am trying to connect crystal report with oracle its showing following error

[image]

1) I have already install drivers and userName,Password and server Name are also right can any one tell what is the actual problem.

Comment: Have you created DSN before connecting to crystal

Comment: i have sold that error ORA-01019 Now New error ORA-12154 TNS Could Not

Comment: This error comes when TNS entry is wrong or TNS entry doesn't exits in `TNSnames.ora` file.

Comment: Could you pls tell me the steps to connect crystal reports to oracle server wich is on another system(not on the same system)....

Comment: I know how to connect in ODBC.. if you are ok with that I will tell you the steps. Let me know your input